# "duration_in_traffic" value is not match with Google Map site

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Live traffic duration time is different from Google Map application and Google Map Distance Matrix API response.

I have tried the following way to get live traffic duration as showing the Google Map application.

First Way

> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
> key=<MyKey>&origins=-33.6771817,151.12005739999995&
> destinations=-33.7704818,150.98828609999998&travelMode=DRIVING&
> departure_time=[Current UTC Time]
> ```

Second Way

> ```
> var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
> service.getDistanceMatrix(
>  {
>   origins: [{lat: <lng>, lng: <lng>}, 'Origin Name'],
>   destinations: ['Destination Name', {lat: <lat>, lng: <lng>}],
>   travelMode: 'DRIVING',
>   drivingOptions: {
>     departureTime: [CurrentUTCTime>],
>     trafficModel: 'best_guess'
>   }
> }
> ```

API results are successfully received but "duration_in_traffic" node value is not match with Google Map Application's live traffic duration time (please refer the attached images)

please assist me what am i doing wrong in this. thanks in advance.

[image: google Map Application Result]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get the exact "draffic_in_duration" value by using the first way with departure_time parameter value as **now**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
key=<MyKey>&origins=-33.6771817,151.12005739999995&
destinations=-33.7704818,150.98828609999998&travelMode=DRIVING&
departure_time=now
```

cheers